# Problem with multi-output and multi-loss functions in tensorflow in python 3

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I want to train LSTM autoencoder. I have N observations with 2 features, one of them is continuous and one is binary: I want to predict continuous by linear + MAE loss and binary by sigmoid + BCE loss. In preprocessing phase I have created sequences, as sliding window of 3 observations. This is how the model looks like

```
input_ae = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))
print(input_ae.shape)
LSTM1 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=6, return_sequences=True, activation = 'selu')(input_ae)
LSTM2 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=1, activation= 'tanh')(LSTM1)
bottleneck = keras.layers.RepeatVector(n=X_train.shape[1])(LSTM2) # bottleneck layer
LSTM3 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=1, return_sequences=True)(bottleneck)
LSTM4 = keras.layers.LSTM(units=6, return_sequences=True, activation = 'selu')(LSTM3)

out1 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation = 'linear')
  )(LSTM4)

out2 = keras.layers.TimeDistributed(
    keras.layers.Dense(units=1, activation = 'sigmoid')
  )(LSTM4)

model = Model(input_ae, outputs=[out1, out2]) 
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=["mae","binary_crossentropy"],
    loss_weights=[1.0, 1.0],) # this is trainable
history = model.fit(X_train, [X_train[:,:,0,np.newaxis], X_train[:,:,1,np.newaxis]],
                epochs=50,
                batch_size=3,
                shuffle=False) # observations are sorted by date !
```

[image: This is how the model looks like]

However I am still getting the following errors regarding topology of the graph of my model. I am new to python and now I do not know whether my coding is wrong or there is some conceptual mistake. Predicted values of variable2 (binary) are still around 0.5 (between 0.4 and 0.6) and they are not pushed towards 0 or 1.

```
2020-05-25 13:44:33.862501: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX AVX2
2020-05-25 13:44:33.882555: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:147] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
Epoch 1/50
2020-05-25 13:44:39.191662: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] remapper failed: Invalid argument: MutableGraphView::MutableGraphView error: node 'loss/time_distributed_2_loss/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/concat' has self cycle fanin 'loss/time_distributed_2_loss/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/concat'.
2020-05-25 13:44:39.229395: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-05-25 13:44:39.247559: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-05-25 13:44:39.345620: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] arithmetic_optimizer failed: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-05-25 13:44:39.363350: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:561] remapper failed: Invalid argument: MutableGraphView::MutableGraphView error: node 'loss/time_distributed_2_loss/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/concat' has self cycle fanin 'loss/time_distributed_2_loss/binary_crossentropy/weighted_loss/concat'.
2020-05-25 13:44:39.383818: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 0, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-05-25 13:44:39.399577: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/dependency_optimizer.cc:717] Iteration = 1, topological sort failed with message: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
2020-05-25 13:44:39.432358: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_function_library_runtime.cc:697] Ignoring multi-device function optimization failure: Invalid argument: The graph couldn't be sorted in topological order.
36/36 [==============================] - 3s 82ms/step - loss: 0.9305 - time_distributed_1_loss: 0.2378 - time_distributed_2_loss: 0.6927
Epoch 2/50
36/36 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.8997 - time_distributed_1_loss: 0.2085 - time_distributed_2_loss: 0.6912
```

The error is each time only in first epoch, later not.

Answer (score 0):

That's not an error, but it's definitely annoying. You can silence this with this line of code **before your Tensorflow import**:

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '3'

from tensorflow import keras # etc
```

Comment: Maybe I should have removed the part with CPU in first two rows. There is however problem with topological ordering of the outputs, which very likely lead to predicting of all binary variables to number in (0.4;0.6) instead of 0 / 1 . Or?

Comment: I think these three issues are unrelated. 1) the topological ordering (whatever that is) doesn't seem to be a problem since your model is learning 2) predictions are like probabilities, if you want 0/1 predictions you need to use `model.predict_classes()`, 3) these warnings can be silenced, no one seems to understand them anyways and they don't prevent learning. Edit: if you're expecting the values to be pushed towards 0 or 1 and it doesn't, it doesn't mean there is an error of any kind

Comment: I think my model is learning, but  incorrectly. Silencing errors which I do not understand is not my cup of tea, I think there is something wrong. When I did the same autoencoder model with sliding window of size 1 (i.e. only 1 observation "per window", it is probably not called a window anymore but I wanted to stick to what I mentioned before), this error did not occur. Also no problem without LSTM layers. So I think I am missing something important there.

Comment: I understand what you mean. It's an interesting issue though, feel free to add bogus data so I can run it. I'm interested in finding out what's happening.

Comment: I can not share the data, it is private. Maybe try to simulate some, the continuous variable can be simulated from some slightly skewed beta distribution and binary of course from bernoulli distribution, prob. of 1 approximately 0.6 might be reasonable. Then you can try to fit the model to the data. I am sorry, I can not share the real data

Comment: That is why I said bogus.

Comment: Ah, right, Mea culpa, sory. I will simulate it so that they are similar. How can I share it then?

Comment: I've had good experiences generating them with numpy. For instance, random continuous data with the same number of columns as the real data. For the output, also random values, or random integers with the right number of categories.

Comment: I generated them with R otherwise it would take eternity, I am not very good in python... How can I send them to you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214594/discussion-between-pikachu-and-nicolas-gervais).